# Как запретить приближение карты при клике на кластер при использовании ObjectManager?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Документация по API яндекс-карт рассказывает как отключить это поведение для `Clusterer` и для отдельных кластеров - но про `ObjectManager` отдельно ничего не говорится. Пытался использовать `manager.clusters.options.set` - но либо такой способ не работает, либо я не правильно пишу название параметра.

Пытался сделать вот так:

```
        var map = new ymaps.Map("map", {
            center: [64.56572586, 102.06531243],
            zoom: 3,
            controls: [],
        })

        var manager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
            clusterize: true,
        })
        manager.clusters.options.set('disableClickZoom', true)
        manager.clusters.options.set('clusterDisableClickZoom', true)
        map.geoObjects.add(manager);

        manager.add([1,2].map(function (index) {
          return { 
            id: index,
            type: 'Feature',
            geometry: {
               type: 'Point',
               coordinates: [64.56572586, 102.06531243],
            }
          }
        }))
```

Аналогичный код с использованием `Clusterer` и `GeoObject` работает, но хотелось бы использовать `ObjectManager`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из оф. документации:

> Опции для кластеров задаются с префиксом cluster. Список опций указан
>   в описании класса ClusterPlacemark;

То есть будет вот так:

```
objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
    clusterize: true,
    clusterDisableClickZoom: true
});
```

Правда, при этом начинает срабатывать дефолтная функция обработки клика (выводит список объектов в кластере). Как это отключить — не знаю.

Comment: Спасибо, это именно то, что было нужно. Действительно, если посмотреть раздел "Справочник Javascript API" - то решение находится сразу же. А вот в "Руководстве разработчика" написано нечто странное...

Comment: PS а "дефолтная" функция открытия балуна отключается через `openBalloonOnClick: false` (с нужными префиксами)